# Have a problem with .load() and IE (All versions)

Tags: jquery, ajax, internet-explorer, load

I have a function that called to a page and try to display a content of a specific DIV element from this page into a other DIV element at the parent page.

In all browsers its work good but in IE it's not working at all.

This is the code I'm using:

```
function showWorks(param) {

    var pageContent = 'work.asp?workId=' + param
    $('div.lightbox-content').load(pageContent + ' #pageContent', function(response, status, xhr) {
        if (status == "success") {
            $('div.lightbox-content #pageContent').addClass('popupContent popupContentWorks');
            openLightbox();
        }
        if (status == "error") {
            var msg = "SOME ERROR TEXT";
            showError(msg);
            openLightbox();
        }
    });
    return false;
};
```

Comment: Are you getting an error? Any more information?

Comment: No error displayed.When I'm writing: $('div.lightbox-content').load(pageContent, function(response, status, xhr)

insted of: $('div.lightbox-content').load(pageContent + ' #pageContent', function(response, status, xhr)

I removed the "#pageContent"...

I'm getting all the page data (but I need only part of the page).

Answer (score 0):

Almost *always* the issue with IE and a partial page [`.load()`](http://api.jquery.com/load/) seemingly doing nothing is due to the selector not finding the element you want, and almost *always*, the issue is invalid markup causing issues there.

Double check that all your elements are valid, opened, closed, matched etc, IE is very intolerant of invalid HTML being used to generate a document fragment (which happens behind the scenes here).  You can use [the W3C Validator to check the page you're trying to load](http://validator.w3.org/).

Comment: All my elements are OK and validate with W3C validator.... :-(

I must find a solutions for this prob...